# iis6 asp.net 4.0 Application Pools

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-6

Currently I have a web application developed in 1.0 and now I'm developing in 4.0. And with this framework version fail me some screens.

I saw that if I IIs Manager -> Application Pools -> show me: DefaultAppPool and Classic Net in the group need to add ASP.NET V4.0, which does not come out. How I can install '

I tried with: "aspnet_regiis-i" and says that is successfully installed but not shown in the application pool.

My machine is a server 2003 with visual studio 2005.

Any help?

thanks

link about my question with image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6pfel30hty3qs6/f4iis.JPG?m

Comment: Are you 100% positive you run `aspnet_regiis` placed on framework 4 folder?

Comment: Yes. My image show the path.

Answer (score 1):

Try Reinstalling/Repairing `Asp.Net 4.0` from offline Installer.
Then run `aspnet_regiis-i` .

Comment: By Offline I mean full setup Reinstall of .Net 4.0 setup File .
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=17718

Comment: Hi, I finished to instal .net 4.0 but it doesn't work. I attach a image with framewroks installed. https://www.dropbox.com/s/gc3gpckcnpscs87/F4INSTALL.bmp